# Is this chip 0.5mm pin pitch?

Tags: fpga, pins, smbus, hot-air

Am I correct in thinking that [this chip](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/altera/EP4CE15E22C7N/544-2666-ND/2295901?WT.z_cid=ref_neda_dkc_buynow) has 0.5mm pin pitch? I don't know where to look for it on the details of the chip!

When I google for '144-LQFP' I found [a link](http://cache.freescale.com/files/shared/doc/package_info/98ASS23177W.pdf) which suggests it is 0.5mm pitch but I would like confirmation!

Comment: The manufacturer will have published a mechanical drawing, and likely a recommended footprint.  Start by tracking that down.  If it's not in the Digi-Key list of documents, go directly to the manufacturer's site.

Comment: For future note, a package denomination is really not enough to know the pitch. As an anecdote, been bitten by a 48-QFN, which can exist in 6x6 mm2 or 7x7 mm2, with a very different footprint and pitches, which is a pain to discover once your pcb is sourced and received...

Comment: Directly on the page you linked there are five datasheet links. These have everything you need, including suggested land patterns. I also recommend the pin connection guideline, which has a checklist and should protect you from the most interesting surprises (e.g. the MSEL pins are referenced to VCCA!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've googled for "altera 144-EQFP" and turned up this [PDF](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/ds/pkgds.pdf). Searched within that document for EQFP and found on page 69 the heading "144-Pin Plastic Enhanced Quad Flat Pack (EQFP)—Wire Bond" with a table of parametric data and an accompanying picture on page 70. The pin pitch is parameter "e", which is "0.50 BSC" (0.5mm pin center to pin center).

The key is to search for the "Supplier Device Package", purported by Digikey.